# How to compare all possibilities of combining a set of lists of numbers, against a requested list of numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I have this list of lists, that have dictionaries in them:

```
[ 
    [{'A': [35, 64, 72]}, {'B': [42, 55, 23]}, {'C': [17, 23, 55]}],
    [{'A': [35, 64, 72]}, {'B': [42, 55, 23]}, {'C': [17, 23, 55]}],
    [{'D': [72]}, {'E': [42]}]
]
```

And I have another list, the requested list, that looks like this:

```
[35, 64, 72, 42, 17, 23, 55]
```

Want I want to achieve is to able to iterate through the available combinations of numbers and see if there are combinations of letters that would match the requested list.

So in this case I would want the output to be

```
['A', 'C', 'E']
```

Because if I combine those together I would get a list with same numbers as the requested list.

I really hope I'm explaining this correctly, and I'm sorry if this is something simple already asked. I couldn't find anything about it, but maybe I'm describing my problem in a wrong way.

Any would be much appreciated! I'm stuck..

Comment: What if you have `{'A': [35, 64, 72]}` and also `{'A': [1,2,3]}`?

Comment: I think that you can first simplify your list of lists to `{'A':[35, 64, 72], 'B':[42, 55, 23], 'C':[17, 23, 55], 'D':[72], 'E':[42]}` first. See if you can solve it.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Fortunately I don't have to consider that, because in the data I work with a different list will alway have a different letter. So if 'A' would be defined as [35, 64, 72], there cannot exist another 'A' with a different list. But that's specific my dataset ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Following additional clarification from the OP regarding the requirements:*

> However, I notice I forgot to mention a requirement. A combination
> always needs to have exactly 1 letter of each of the major lists. So
> in this example, there must be one out of A,B,C, another one out of
> A,B,C and on out of D, E.

*I have decided to leave my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63245168/13596037), and add this one alongside it for the slightly different use case.*

---

---

Still preprocess the input data, although less heavily - this time a list of dictionaries (again with sets as dictionary values):

```
data_in = [ 
    [{'A': [35, 64, 72]}, {'B': [42, 55, 23]}, {'C': [17, 23, 55]}],
    [{'A': [35, 64, 72]}, {'B': [42, 55, 23]}, {'C': [17, 23, 55]}],
    [{'D': [72]}, {'E': [42]}]
]

target_list = [35, 64, 72, 42, 17, 23, 55]

data = []
for sublist in data_in:
    dct = {}
    for dct_in in sublist:        
        dct.update({k: set(v) for k, v in dct_in.items()})
    data.append(dct)

target = set(target_list)

print(data)
# [{'A': {64, 72, 35}, 'B': {42, 23, 55}, 'C': {17, 55, 23}}, {'A': {64, 72, 35}, 'B': {42, 23, 55}, 'C': {17, 55, 23}}, {'D': {72}, 'E': {42}}]

print(target)    
# {64, 35, 72, 42, 17, 55, 23}
```

And now again a recursive solution, but a slightly different one from before:

```
def find_combos(target, data):
    for k, v in data[0].items():
        if not (v - target):
            remaining_data = data[1:]
            remaining_target = target - v
            if remaining_data:
                for lst in find_combos(remaining_target, remaining_data):
                    yield [k] + lst
            elif not remaining_target:
                yield [k]

for combo in find_combos(target, data):
    print(combo)
```

This gives:

```
['A', 'C', 'E']
['C', 'A', 'E']
```

If you want to avoid "duplicates" (only looking at the keys here - this is dependent on the same keys having the same associated values in the input), you could do something like this:

```
combos_dict = {tuple(sorted(combo)): combo
               for combo in find_combos(target, data)}

uniq_combos = list(combos_dict.values())
print(uniq_combos)
```

which gives:

```
[['A', 'C', 'E']]
```

---

---

**Final update** - further modification to deal with further new information that repeats are also possible in the input lists.  Hence use counts dictionaries instead of sets.  To implement this:

- In preprocessing the input data, use `from collections import Counter` and replace `set` with `Counter` in the two places where it appears, giving:

```
data = [{'A': Counter({35: 1, 64: 1, 72: 1}), 'B': Counter({42: 1, 55: 1, 23: 1}), 'C': Counter({17: 1, 23: 1, 55: 1})}, {'A': Counter({35: 1, 64: 1, 72: 1}), 'B': Counter({42: 1, 55: 1, 23: 1}), 'C': Counter({17: 1, 23: 1, 55: 1})}, {'D': Counter({72: 1}), 'E': Counter({42: 1})}]

target = Counter({35: 1, 64: 1, 72: 1, 42: 1, 17: 1, 23: 1, 55: 1})
```

- Then replace

```
        if not (v - target):
```

with

```
        if all(target.get(kk, 0) >= vv for kk, vv in v.items()):
```

- Finally, replace

```
            remaining_target = target - v
```

with

```
            remaining_target = target.copy()
            for kk, vv in v.items():
                remaining_target[kk] -= vv
                if remaining_target[kk] == 0:
                    del remaining_target[kk]
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! I've learned a lot about generators and sets. I have one question, because once again I forgot to something. the target_list could have duplicate entries, which are excluded by the set(target_list), any way to make a set like object that allows duplicates?

Comment: @Cennnn First, note that I've edited it with a bugfix so please pick up the latest version. Secondly, no there isn't. You could instead replace sets throughout with dictionaries produced by `collections.Counter` from the input lists. But the tests would be more complicated - the `if not (v - target)` would have to be a check that for every key in `v`, the corresponding key exists in `target` with a greater or equal value (count). And the `target - v` would have to be a dictionary where you subtract off each of these values.

Comment: Again, thank you, I changed what you told me to, and it works! I also have duplicate values in the data aswell, so the collections.Counter fixes that too! Thank you so much

Comment: @Cennnn I've now added final update to my answer to handle this, although it sounds like you may have it sorted anyway.

Comment: Thank you again! I applied your final update, it was a little different from my implementation, it appears I made a mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

The OP has added requirements in the comments below this question.  It is sufficiently altered, although related, that I have decided to leave this answer in place (to answer the question as shown) and add a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63248369/13596037) relating to that case.

---

---

The problem breaks down into two parts.

1. Getting your input data into a more convenient format:

```
data_in = [ 
    [{'A': [35, 64, 72]}, {'B': [42, 55, 23]}, {'C': [17, 23, 55]}],
    [{'A': [35, 64, 72]}, {'B': [42, 55, 23]}, {'C': [17, 23, 55]}],
    [{'D': [72]}, {'E': [42]}]
]

target_list = [35, 64, 72, 42, 17, 23, 55]

data = {}
for sublist in data_in:
    for dct in sublist:
        data.update({k: set(v) for k, v in dct.items()})

target = set(target_list)
        
print(data)
# {'A': {64, 72, 35}, 'B': {42, 23, 55}, 'C': {17, 55, 23}, 'D': {72}, 'E': {42}}

print(target)
# {64, 35, 72, 42, 17, 55, 23}
```

2. Having done that, solving the interesting problem.  This can be done with a recursive approach:

```
def find_combos(target, items):
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(items):
        if not (v - target):
            remaining = target - v
            if remaining:                
                for lst in find_combos(remaining, items[i + 1 :]):
                    yield [k] + lst
            else:
                yield [k]


for combo in find_combos(target, list(data.items())):
    print(combo)
```

Prints:

```
['A', 'C', 'E']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! Your code is quite advanced for me but I think I understand it.

However, I notice I forgot to mention a requirement. A combination always needs to have exactly 1 letter of each of the major lists. So in this example, there must be one out of A,B,C, another one out of A,B,C and on out of D, E.

But by simplifying the data, as @Oscar916 also proposed, I can not do this anymore. In the example it works, but in more complex cases I'm unable to get a good result

Comment: @Cennnn I have decided on balance to deal with this by means of a separate answer rather than start editing this one.